# How to prevent users from accessing admin pages

Tags: php, mysql

I want to prevent any other user from accessing the admin page unless the role is admin.

Also the admin can access the employees page even if the role is not correct.

I don't know what's wrong with my code why it is not working.

On all of my php code I have a require once for this page call "check_login.php"

here is the check_login.php code for admin pages

```
<?php

session_start();
$current_user = $_SESSION['fullname'];

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    $myusername = $_SESSION['username'];

    include '../db_config/connection.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE ent_id='$myusername' AND role IN ('Admin', 'Manager', 'Supervisor')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $current_user_id = $row['user_id'];
        }
    } else {
        header("../?login_err=You must be an Administrator");
    }
    $conn->close();

} else {
    header("location:../?login_err=You must login first");
}

?>
```

and here's the check_login.php code for employees

```
<?php

session_start();
$current_user = $_SESSION['fullname'];
$current_empid = $_SESSION['user_index'];

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    $myusername = $_SESSION['username'];

    include '../db_config/connection.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE ent_id='$myusername' AND role = 'Employee'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $current_user_id = $row['user_id'];
        }
    } else {
        header("../build/login.php?login_err=You must be an Employee");
    }
    $conn->close();

} else {
    header("location:../build/login.php?login_err=You must login first");
}
?>
```

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Where is the mentioned check_login.php code?

Comment: @jcjr those are the check_login.php. One for admin and for employees.

Comment: you shouldn't use `../` urls - not all servers are set up to be relative - use `Location: /index.php` (example)

Comment: Why do you use a `while` loop? Can there really be more than one row with the same username? And if there is, you're just setting `$current_user_id` to the last one, so you could just use `LIMIT 1` in the query.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is not valid, you need to `exit()` after calling `header()` to redirect. Otherwise, the rest of the script that calls these scripts will still run.